# swift program to get files from url to play as well as for download

Tags: swift, url, avfoundation

I'm want to play files from url, and url are saved in array and play them online .

no idea how to do this any help would be very appreciable.

fatal error coming

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://royalwap.net/48-740090s/Na%20Na%20Na%20Na.mp3")

    let urlRequest = NSURLRequest( URL: url! )

    var error: NSError? = nil

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler: {response, data , error in
        if error != nil {
            println("There was an error")
        } else {

      self.player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url , error: nil )

     self.player.play()
    }})

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use AVPlayer to stream the audio from url, you wont be able to do it with AVAudioPlayer unless you download it.

```
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://royalwap.net/48-740090s/Na%20Na%20Na%20Na.mp3")!

    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: url)

    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)

    player.play()
```

Comment: That should work.  You might also try the prepare method and then you will get a call back once the media buffer is ready.  Are you trying to download it and play it locally or stream it from the url?